# Create directories and files on the fly for each web page visited

Tags: bash, applescript

I wrote the following script to document the webpages I visit. When run, the text content of the active tab will be logged and stored in a directory. What I would like to be able to do is have a new directory and file created on the fly every time the page changes; whether another tab is activated or another url is loaded in the same tab. As it is right now, the script will log all content but it will log all content in the directory for the web page that was open when the script was started. So if I start the script while this page is active, any other page I visit will be logged in the same file and directory directly below the content logged from this page.

```
#!/bin/bash

getChrome() {   
    osascript -e \
    'tell application "Google_Chrome" to tell the active tab of window 1 to execute javascript "document.body.innerText"'
}

url="$(osascript -e 'tell application "Google_Chrome" to set the_URL to the URL of the active tab of window 1')"
site="$(echo $url | cut -d/ -f3)" 

# removes . and replaces with _
if [[ $(echo "$site") =~ '.' ]]; then 
    site="$(echo "${site//./_}")"
fi

ds="$(date "+%m-%d-%y")"
dir="$HOME/Desktop/netlogs/$site/$ds"

if [ ! -d "${dir}" ]; then mkdir -p "${dir}"; fi

doc="${site}_LOG.txt"
file="${dir}/${doc}"

printf "\nBEGIN\n\n" | tee -a $file
while true
do 
    getChrome | while read lines
    do 
        echo $lines 
        # This if statement doesn't work.
        # Included here to show intent
        if [[ $url != $url ]]; then
            break 1
        fi  
    done 
done | awk '!seen[$0]++ { print; fflush() }' | tee -a $file
```

In trying to figure out a way of doing this I wrote this Applescript to get some audio feedback on what is happening when I change tabs:

```
tell application "Google_Chrome" to tell window 1
    tell the active tab
        set the_url to the URL
        repeat
            if the URL is not the_url then
                set the_url to the URL
                say "nope"
            else
                say "yep"
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

Aside from being pretty annoying, it does let me know that a change of url is recognized. But I can't figure out how to take this same idea and use it to make a new directory and file when the url changes. I'm not looking for an AppleScript solution necessarily. In fact I prefer to avoid AppleScript as much as possible as it usually brings headaches and eventual rage quitting. But when it works it works well and I'd be happy with any method that does that.

Comment: pluse uno for interesting code and "rage quitting" (LOL). I feel your pain. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! Hey by chance would you like to share any sage wisdom with me good sir? Pointers, criticisms, ideas, improvements?

Comment: Hmm... Maybe I'm overthinking this too much. Re-reading your code, is your primary interest in getting the test `if [[ $url != $url ]]; then break 1 ; fi` to work? Of course you really meant `if [[ "$prev_url" != "$url" ]]; then break 1 ; fi` didn't you? ;-) ?

Comment: My apologies for not responding sooner. The last comment you wrote made me think about it in a different way. And I really try to figure things out so I know it rather than being told how to do it.. I hope that sentence makes sense. But yeah I figured out how to create new directories every time the url changes. I guess I'll post it as answer to the question. I'd still appreciate any feedback you have to give on any of part of it. And feel free to post a better or alternative answer as well if you feel like it. `[[ "$prev_url" != "$url" ]]` was what did it for me. So thank you very much.

Comment: OK, glad that helped. Post your improved version as your own answer and accept it. I'll comment on it, but leave a comment here so I will know you have posted. Good luck.

Comment: Ok I posted the script as an answer if you'd like to take a look at it and tell me what you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Functions:

```
#!/bin/bash

getSAFARI() {   
    osascript -e \
    'tell application "Safari" to tell current tab of window 1 to do javascript "document.body.innerText"' 2>&1
}
getCHROME() {   
    osascript -e \
    'tell application "Google_Chrome" to tell active tab of window 1 to execute javascript "document.body.innerText"' 2>&1 
}
SURF() {
    if [[ "$(echo $current_url)" != "$(echo $url)" ]]; then
        echo -e "\nEND\n\n" | tee -a $file 2>&1
        break 1
    elif [[ "$(echo $current_url)" = https://example.com/*/ ]]; then
        regex='[[:alnum:]]'
    else
        regex='[\p{L}]'
    fi
    get$BROWSER | while read lines; do echo $lines | grep -E $regex; done < <(get$BROWSER)
}
SET_VARIABLES() {

    ds="$(date "+%m_%d_%y")"
    site="$(echo $url | cut -d/ -f3)"
    dir="$HOME/Desktop/netlogs/$ds/$site"
    doc="${site}_LOG.txt"
    file="${dir}/${doc}"
    if [ ! -d "${dir}" ]; then mkdir -p "${dir}"; fi
    echo '-----------------------------' | tee -a $file 2>&1
    date | tee -a $file 2>&1
    echo -ne "$url\n" | tee -a $file 2>&1
    echo '-----------------------------' | tee -a $file 2>&1
    printf "BEGIN\n\n" | tee -a $file 2>&1

}
```

### Script:

```
echo "Choose your browser"
echo "1) Safari"
echo "2) Chrome"
echo
read -sn1 choice
while true
do
    case $choice in 
        [1])
        BROWSER="SAFARI"
        while true
        do
            url="$(osascript -e 'tell app "Safari" to tell the current tab of window 1 to get the url as text' 2>&1 | grep -v 'execution error')"
            if [[ $url = '' ]]; then echo "Now exiting" && exit; fi
            SET_VARIABLES
            while true
            do 
                current_url="$(osascript -e 'tell app "Safari" to tell the current tab of window 1 to get the url as text' 2>&1 | grep -v 'execution error')"
                SURF
                if [[ $current_url = '' ]]; then echo "Now exiting" && exit; fi
            done | awk '!seen[$0]++ { print; fflush() }' | tee -a $file
        done
        break
        ;;

        [2])
        BROWSER="CHROME"
        while true
        do
            url="$(osascript -e 'tell app "Google_Chrome" to tell the active tab of window 1 to get the url as text' 2>&1 | grep -v 'error')"
            if [[ $url = '' ]]; then echo "Now exiting" && exit; fi
            SET_VARIABLES
            while true
            do 
                current_url="$(osascript -e 'tell app "Google_Chrome" to tell the active tab of window 1 to get the url as text' 2>&1 | grep -v 'error')"
                SURF
                if [[ $current_url = '' ]]; then echo "Now exiting" && exit; fi
            done | awk '!seen[$0]++ { print; fflush() }' | tee -a $file
        done
        break
        ;;

        *)
        echo 'Invalid Selection'
        exit
        ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: Looks good to me with a few minor issues. 1 don't see the need for `2>&1` after the `tee -a` commands. 2. Posix scripts should only have all UPPER CASE variables for the Posixly defined variables (HOME, PWD (and others)), Camel-case is considered correct usage for shell scripting. 3, you may have valid reasons for using %m-%d-%y for your date format, but using `%Y-%m-%d` gives you files that automatically sort themselves to have the newest file at the bottom of your screen when  you use `ls -ltr` .  4. If `[[ $curr_url == '' ]]` is considered a problem, then you might want to `exit 1`.

Comment: 5. Be consistent, and dbl-quote all your variable usage, especially `"$file"` . Overall, this is very good code, so in the future, you should use http://codereview.stackexchange.com to ask for opinions there for "is there anything better I can do" type of Qs. Your initial problem "why  isn't this working" was on topic ;-) .. Good luck and keep posting.

Comment: Still looking. I don't see what `get$Browser | while read .... done ; < <(get$Browser)` is supposed to work, but I don't want to spend further time on that, so again, much better than average shell script code in a Q, so keep posting (to the appropriate forum). Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. What you said about the `%Y-%m-%d` format is something I was unaware of. That will be very helpful. The reason for the upper case variables is simply readability while writing as it makes them easier to find when my brain turns to mush. The reason for `get$Browser | while read .... done ; < <(get$Browser)` and I assume you mean the `< <(get$Browser)` part of it - is because in a chatroom, this is the only way I have been able to continuously update the information written to file as it occurs in realtime on the website. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Kinda funny, the problem that is now resolved has created a new issue that needs to be resolved. Now whenever tabs are changed, it creates a new directory and document if needed and writes the information to that file. BUT when you then switch back to the previous tab, the information that was already written to file for that tab, is appended to the same file again. It would be better if it only wrote to file new information not already contained within the document. But I will think about this and try to figure it out. If I can't, I'll ask a new question. Thanks again for the help!! :-j

Comment: That won't be easy. You can easily either "append to" (`>>`), or "create new" (`>`) file. Integrating two (or more) versions of the same html will be difficult. That would be a whole separate program, done in a tool with higher level text processing functions (or writing them yourself), which could be a major project. Maybe you want to parse the data so it could be loaded into a database and then keep a "tree" structure that could be reassembled into any version you care to specify. Not clear about your ultimate use of this, and getting way beyond helping you fix a coding problem, so GoodLuck!

Comment: lol I'm not even clear what my ultimate use of this is. I really do appreciate all your help. Thank you again.